# How to not duplicate when adding data in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How to not duplicate when adding data in `JTable` because when I am adding in `JTable` it always duplicate the same data.

```java
public void buyproduct() {
    String name = code_cart1.getText();
    try {
        con = Connector.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT `Code`, `Category`, `ProductName`, `Size`, `Quantity`, `Price`, `Sub-Total` FROM `product_table` WHERE Code = ?");
        pst.setString(1, name);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            int currentqty = rs.getInt("Quantity");
            int pricenew = Integer.parseInt(price_cart1.getText());
            int qtynew = Integer.parseInt(quantity_cart1.getText());
            int tot = pricenew * qtynew;
            if (qtynew > currentqty || qtynew == 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Out of Stock!");
            } else {
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) cart_Display.getModel();
                model.addRow(new Object[]{code_cart1.getText(),
                                          category_cart1.getText(),
                                          productname_cart1.getText(),
                                          size_cart1.getText(),
                                          quantity_cart1.getText(),
                                          price_cart1.getText(),
                                          tot});
                int sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < cart_Display.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(cart_Display.getValueAt(i, 6).toString());
                }
                SubTotal_Cart_text.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
                SubTotal_Cart_text1.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
                code_cart1.setText("");
                category_cart1.setText("");
                productname_cart1.setText("");
                size_cart1.setText("");
                quantity_cart1.setText("");
                price_cart1.setText("");
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Never catch exceptions without handle it. Also do not catch the base class Exception. Catch only specific exceptions

Comment: You should take the value from the resultset

Comment: Create a new `TableModel` and fill that; Remove all the existing content from the existing `TableModel` before you up date it

Comment: You can use the `DefaultTableModel.setRowCount(...)` method to clear the data before adding more data.

Comment: [mcve] please..